# What is this port on my 1999 laptop?

Tags: laptop, port

My Maxdata Artist Harvard SL Pro laptop, dating from 1999, has this port on its back side. I have never seen this anywhere else, neither can I identify the little icon to its side. The size of the port is ca. 1×3 cm. What is it?

[image]

Comment: Expansion or docking port... usually proprietary.

Comment: Icon means nothing to me, other than "expansion".  Given how it looks like 2 parts, one upside down of the other, I wonder if it is PCMCIA Type 3, which was basically 2 slots.  Or might be some other add-on, like RAM.  If not PCMCIA, it doesn't look like a very widely used standard.

Comment: Related: [Are hardware (port, cable, etc.) visual identification questions allowed or not?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7647/are-hardware-port-cable-etc-visual-identification-questions-allowed-or-not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [owners manual](http://ftp.maxdata.de/MAXDATA_Notebooks/Archive/Manuals/Archive/MAXDATA%20Harvard%20SL%20Pro/MANUAL_SLPRO_D.PDF) it's a Port-Replicator Port, used for a docking station or port expansion unit.

My German isn't good enough to interpret much more than that, but Maxdata has manuals, user guides, drivers, etc all available on their [FTP site](http://ftp.maxdata.de/MAXDATA_Notebooks/)

Comment: Nice, that's true. It can be used for [Port-Replicator bars](ftp://ftp.maxdata.de/Accessories/Accessories%20Notebook/Datasheets/DB_Port_Replikator_D.pdf) with lots of additional ports.